How to redirect from embedded browser to main browser, on mobile devices? (Next.JS)
I've been trying to force a redirect on my nextjs app.
For instance, someone sends a link to my app on Instagram. When I open it on Instagram, it opens in Instagram's embedded browser. I want it to redirect to Safari as soon as it opens on the embedded browser on Instagram, Linkedin, etc.
The code that l've implemented after reading documentation and articles, manages to open safari, but does a google search using the default search engine.
How do I fix this?
https://felixcarmona.com/solving-google-login-issues-linkedin-ios/
This is the reference article I used.
utils/detectEmbeddedBrowser.js
import { android _regex, ios_regex } from "./regex/ regex";
export const detectEmbeddedBrowser = 0) => {
code not included due to text limit }
export const handleEmbeddedBrowserRedirect =
0 => {
if (detectEmbeddedBrowser)) {
const islOS =
ios_regex.test(navigator.user Agent) &&!
window.MSStream; const isAndroid =
android.
_regex.test(navigator.userAgent);
const url = window.location.href;
if (islOS) {
alert("Please open this page in Safari for the best experience.");
window.location.href = x-web-search: //?
${url};
else if (isAndroid) {
alert("Please open this page in Chrome for the best experience.");
window.location.href = googlechrome: / /
navigate?url=${url};
}
// Fallback for other environments
else 1
alert("For the best experience, please open this page in your default browser.");
 }
}

I’ve tried this, I expected that it would open safari and redirected to the desired url. But instead of going to that URL, it does a search using the default search engine of the browser. I’m thinking if there’s something like ‘x-web-open’ instead of x-web-search, since search makes it obvious that it will SEARCH instead of putting the URL in the address bar.
